# Intersections and Cosets

Tags: group-theory

This question is from my abstract algebra class.

Q: If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $g \in G$, show that
$g(H \cap K) = gH \cap gK$.

Pseudo answer:
What I was trying to do was show that if $H$ and $K$ are cosets of $G$, they are both unique and the intersection on both sides will be equal to nothing.

Is this the right approach?
 Can someone show me how to prove this.

Thanks,
Jonathan Parziale

Comment: What do you mean by "therefore they are unique". Also, the intersection is not necessarily empty (what if $H = K$?)

Comment: What about taking an element on each side and show that its already on the other side?

Comment: By the definition of cossets all cossets are unique. otherwise they are equal. So yes i forgot about when H=K by the definition of cossets 2 cossets can't intersect O.W they are the same cosset.

Comment: I was thinking in terms of cossets since the chapter is on cossets.

Comment: By 'unique' you presumably mean 'disjoint' ie, they have empty intersection. Two cosets _of the same subgroup_ are either disjoint or equal but there is no reason that cosets gH and gK of different subgroups would be (indeed as the question shows they will not be).

Answer (score 3):

$H$ and $K$ are not cosets of $G,$ they are subgroups of $G$. For each $g,$ we have the following:

- $gH$ is a coset of $H$ in $G.$
- $gK$ is a coset of $K$ in $G.$
- $g(H\cap K)$ is a coset of $H\cap K$ in $G.$

Keep in mind that $$gH=\{gh:h\in H\}\\gK=\{gk:k\in K\}\\g(H\cap K)=\{ga:a\in H\cap K\}$$ What you need to show, then, is that every element of $gH\cap gK$ is an element of $g(H\cap K),$ and vice-versa.

As a side note, it is true that distinct cosets of *the same subgroup* are disjoint, but that is irrelevant, here. In fact, $gH$ and $gK$ will *never* be disjoint for $g\in G$ and for subgroups $H,K$ of $G,$ since $g$ will be an element of both. (Why?)

Comment: Yes that makes sense i wasnt looking at gH and gK as cossets.That makes sense Thank you